# How can I make the custom properties of an aspect searchable in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created an aspect which I add to a user and am looking documentation which explains how to make these properties searchable. I have seen some posts on the forums which talk about adding configurations to the web-client-config, but I think this has to do with the explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the properties must be indexed - see [Additional Property Capabilities](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Additional_Property_Capabilities) in the [Data Dictionary Guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide).

If you have done that and you are using a recent version of Share, then it is possible to perform a basic search via the simple search box, specifying the property name and value, e.g.

`cm:title:"Specific title I am looking for"`

See the [Search help info](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/search.html) for more background. The query syntax is powerful, but relies on users knowing this. For general use, you should create an advanced search form definition as Heiko suggests.

Comment: Do I have to set those values for every property of my aspect? I'm wondering whether there is a way to shortcut it and set it for the whole aspect as it has something like 16 properties.

Comment: You mean you want to return items where the value matches any one of a number of properties, where those properties are all defined by a common aspect? If so, the answer is no. You can only search for the presence of an aspect.

Answer (score 4):

you need to define a Share search form:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Advanced_Search

Comment: Is there anyway I can also implement it for a simple search??

Answer (score 1):

If you want your custom property to show up in the form, you need to define a search form like Robert has said. If you want your users to simply type your custom prop in the search box you can follow Will's advice. If you want your users to type a simple query in the simple search box and you want that query to search your custom properties by default, you need to extend

$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.lib.js

Go look at the getQueryTemplate() function. You'll see that it defines the search template that's used by default. You'll also notice that the comment says the search template is in the web script's config, which is search.get.config.xml.

So, override that config using the normal web script extension mechanism, and add your own custom properties to the template. Then, whenever anyone does a search in the simple search box, it will also search your custom props.